# C# generic class and EqualityComparer

Tags: c#, generics, static, icomparable, icomparer

Could anyone explain me what's wrong in the following class declaration:

```
private class PriorityQueueEntry<TPriorityValue,IIdentifiableEntry,IType> :
        IComparer<PriorityQueueEntry<TPriorityValue,IIdentifiableEntry,IType>>
            where TPriorityValue : IComparable
            where IIdentifiableEntry : Identifier<IType>
    {
        public TPriorityValue Priority{get;private set;}
        public IIdentifiableEntry Entry{get;private set;}

        public PriorityQueueEntry(TPriorityValue val,IIdentifiableEntry entry)
        {
            Priority = val;
            Entry = entry;
        }
        public int Compare(PriorityQueueEntry<TPriorityValue,IIdentifiableEntry,IType> first, PriorityQueueEntry<TPriorityValue,IIdentifiableEntry,IType> second) 
        {
            if (first.Priority.CompareTo(second.Priority) < 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (first.Priority.CompareTo(second.Priority) > 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return EqualityComparer<IIdentifiableEntry>.Default.Equals( first.Entry.Id, second.Entry.Id);
        }
    }
```

The compiler complaing on the line where I use EqualityComparer. The error is the following:

> error CS0176: Static member `object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be
>   accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name
>   instead

I can't see where I'm using an instance reference.

---

Sorry, my fault. I posted an incomplete question. 
Just for completeness, Idetifier class is just the following:

```
public interface Identifier<ID_TYPE> 
{
    ID_TYPE Id{get;set;}
}
```

using EqualityComparer there, was due to a copy and paste mistake(sorry guys, too much generic code today).

Of course my question was misposed, because I didn't give you all the elements you needed to answer (I'll remove it soon).
I needed `IType` to be `IConvertible`.
Thanks to all anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved this way:

```
private class PriorityQueueEntry<TPriorityValue,IIdentifiableEntry,IType> :
        IComparer<PriorityQueueEntry<TPriorityValue,IIdentifiableEntry,IType>>
            where TPriorityValue : IComparable
            where IIdentifiableEntry : Identifier<IType>
            where IType : IConvertible
    {
        public TPriorityValue Priority{get;private set;}
        public IIdentifiableEntry Entry{get;private set;}

        public PriorityQueueEntry(TPriorityValue val,IIdentifiableEntry entry)
        {
            Priority = val;
            Entry = entry;
        }
        public int Compare(PriorityQueueEntry<TPriorityValue,IIdentifiableEntry,IType> first, PriorityQueueEntry<TPriorityValue,IIdentifiableEntry,IType> second) 
        {
            if (first.Priority.CompareTo(second.Priority) < 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (first.Priority.CompareTo(second.Priority) > 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return first.Entry.Id.ToUInt32(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo) < first.Entry.Id.ToUInt32(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo) ? -1:1; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an instance reference:

```
EqualityComparer<IIdentifiableEntry>.Default
```

The first problem is that you don't *want* to call `object.Equals(object, object)` at all. You really want to be calling the method on the equality comparer - but you're trying to call it with arguments which aren't convertible to `IIdentifieableEntry`.

The second problem is that you're trying to perform an *ordering* comparison, not an *equality* comparison, so you want `Comparer<T>`, not `EqualityComparer<T>`.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but this code would at least *compile*:

```
return Comparer<IIdentifiableEntry>.Default.Compare(first.Entry, second.Entry);
```

If you really want to compare the Id properties, you need an equality comparer *for the ID property type* - and we don't know what that type is.

I suspect it's more likely that you really want *something* like this:

```
return Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(first.Entry.Id, second.Entry.Id);
```

... but it depends on the type of `Id`.

Comment: This code won't compile since Equals returns a bool and the method should return an int

Comment: actually IType : IConvertible solved my problems. Sorry for the incomplete question.

Answer (score 3):

You have not shown the declaration of Identifier nor EqualityComparer.  But I assume you need to change the line to something like:

```
return EqualityComparer<IIdentifiableEntry>.Default.Equals<IType>( first.Entry.Id, second.Entry.Id);
```

**[EDIT]**

As per Jon's comment.  You do not want to equality comparer at all.  Asumming that that Entry.Id is IComparable, then just:

```
return first.Entry.Id.CompareTo(second.Entry.Id);
```

I would recommend that Entry is restricted to IComparable, so we get something like:

class PriorityQueueEntry>
            where TPriorityValue : IComparable
            where TEntry : IComparable
    {
        public TPriorityValue Priority{get;private set;}
        public TEntry Entry{get;private set;}

```
    public PriorityQueueEntry(TPriorityValue val, TIdentifiableEntry entry)
    {
        Priority = val;
        Entry = entry;
    }
    public int Compare(PriorityQueueEntry<TPriorityValue, TEntry first, PriorityQueueEntry<TPriorityValue, TEntry> second) 
    {
        if (first.Priority.CompareTo(second.Priority) < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (first.Priority.CompareTo(second.Priority) > 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return first.Enrtry.CompareTo(second.Entry);
    }
}
```

You may want to add some null checks if TEntry is a class.

Comment: `Equals` is not templated method in `EqualityComarer<T>`

Comment: My bad.  I googled it and it only returned IEqualityComparer.  Hmmm.  Please disregard previous answer.  I'll edit a new answer.